# Installing Multiverse package for STM development in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, stm

I am trying to use the 'multiverse' https://github.com/pveentjer/Multiverse/tree/master/multiverse-core package in Java to do some STM development. I am using Java 17 with IntelliJ, I am really struggling to get the package to work and can't find much documentation on how to install the package.
These are the import statements I have:

```
import org.multiverse.api.references.*;
import org.multiverse.api.StmUtils;
```

I am getting the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'multiverse'". Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.